# Error when using http in node_package_manager

Tags: react-native, npm

I am not sure why I am getting this error message from npm, but it is saying that

error:

> Error: While trying to resolve module `http` from file
> `C:\Users\path\node_modules\express\lib\request.js`, the package
> `C:\Users\path\node_modules\http\package.json` was successfully found.
> However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that
> could not be resolved
>
> (`C:\Users\path\node_modules\http\index`. Indeed, none of these files
> exist:

The thing about this error messsage, it asked me before that `http` and `path` did not exist in my `node_modules`. So I installed those two packages to my npm. Now it is giving that error message and I am not sure how I can resolve this. Any idea how to fix this problem?

I have tried deleting the **npm** and then reinstalling back in and it again give me the same error.

I have also tried using

`npx react-native start --reset-cache`

and I am still facing the same error message.